# Aggregate cells of worldclim geographically to estimate standard deviation of 10min resolution by using 30s resolution

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, r-raster, elevation

I have to estimate topographic information of certain areas. Here a want to use data of worldclim. I need to estimate the the standard deviation of elevation for each 30s cell, that occurs within a 10min cell. However, I really do not know how to this. I somehow have to aggregate the cells geographically...

I first extract the required data of worldclim, elevations for 10min and for 30s (here I just picked a random number for lon and lat). I also provide one of my coordinates I use.

```
alt <- getData("worldclim",var="alt",res=10)

alt05_1 <- getData('worldclim', var='alt', res=0.5, lon=5, lat=45)

lats <- c(46.06667, 46.60134)

lons <- c(7.600000, 9.965973)

coords <- data.frame(x=lons,y=lats)

points_alt <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = alt@crs)

values_alt <- extract(alt,points_alt)

altitude <- cbind.data.frame(coordinates(points_alt),values_alt)
```

So with this, I am of course able to extract the elevation for both relosutions, however, how am I able to extract all mean elevations from every 30s cell that occur in the 10min cell of e. g. the first coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you get are with a `Raster` format. So, you should use functions of `library(raster)`. You can directly calculate the standard deviation through the `aggregate` function. Parameter `fact` is the size of the aggregation, here from 0.5 to 10, `fact=10/0.5`:

```
alt05_1 <- getData('worldclim', var='alt', res=0.5, lon=5, lat=45)
sd_alt05 <- aggregate(alt05_1, fact = 10/0.5, fun = sd)
```

To get the mean, you may use the same function. `mean` is the default by the way:

```
mean_alt05 <- aggregate(alt05_1, fact = 10/0.5, fun = mean)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, I have a question and a problem. At first the question: Why do I need the 10min resolution to calculate the mean/sd of the 30s cells? I thought it might be done indepentant from each other.
My problem now is now, that I need to have all 30s means of specific 10min cells to calculate the sd of these 10min cell, based in the means of their 30 means. But how do I do this? In which way can I specifically define or call a cell of interest which includes my coordinates, and furthermore how can a extract the mean of every single 30s cell, that occurs in the 10min cell?

Comment: My aggregate function does exactly what you ask. It calculate the sd of all 30sec cells in each 10min cells. There is no more step needed as far as I understand your question.

Comment: Okay. I was confused, cause it generales a new stack, just like the ones containing information about the elevation. Do I now have automatically the wanted sd of a 10min cell, if i insert my coordinates?

Comment: So do I now have the sd of a specific 10min cell, when I insert coordinates like above?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert coordinates"? You mean extract raster information at specific data locations ?    `sd_alt05` calculates the sd of all 30sec cells in a 10min cell, which is what you will extract at a coordinates falling wherever into this 10min resolution cell. If this is what you asked, please click to accept the answer. If you have more questions on a script that doesn't work, please create a new clear question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to annoy you, but this is not easy to understand for me, thus I was not sure, if my question is answered already. So, I would be very happy if you could help me here to understand my output. When I use `sd_alt05`as I did with `alt` above in my example, I get one value for every of my coordinates e.g. 225,4. Is this now the sd of the 10 min cell? Cause that is what I need and what I tried to calculate basd on the 30s resolution.

Comment: Yes. This is the `sd` of the 10min cell in which your point fall in. This `sd` is calculated with all the 30s cells that were in this same 10min cell.

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry for my struggle and confusion.